# xtext writing and interpreter

Tags: eclipse, interpreter, dsl, xtext

currently I am writing an interpreter for my DSL which is launched from a menu in a eclipse application . The interpreter read the active file with:

`IXtextDocument document = ((XtextEditor) activeEditor).getDocument().get();`
(return a String)

Then I read line by line with a scanner the active file , but is really hard , reading all lines and make switches and ifs for every possibility for their execution .

is there a way to use my grammar information(know what is the line: declaration , function , ...) while I read the active file in the eclipse application ? , or is there a better way to implement this without reading the file like a normal string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IXtextDocument` implements `IReadAccess<XtextResource>` interface, so you should be able to call `editor.document.readOnly(...)`, like here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/blob/01ffa30f58160e4c13cb193da3d1e21a40e0d508/org.eclipse.xtext.ui.tests/tests/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/tests/editor/SimpleEditorTest.java#L64

Comment: i did what you said , but in this point , i was trying to get the information from the resource 

`TreeIterator<EObject> contents = resource.getAllContents();
                      while(contents.hasNext()){
                       EObject o = contents.next();
                       console.out.println(o.eClass().toString());
                       console.out.println(o.toString());
                      }`
(console.out is only for write in my own console )but the output is strange or incomplete for some types , any idea how i should read the resource for my interpreter?thanks so much

Comment: Usually you do `resource.getContents().get(0)` if you don't have inferred stuff, there is only one root. After that you traverse the model with your interpreter. A model can be broken if a file has errors, your interpreter should be able to handle it.